# Publish multiple Content Types at once in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type-hub

I'm working on setting up modern sites in SharePoint Online (Office 365). We're using a Content Type Hub to manage all the content types.

I've been automating the creation of Content Types using PowerShell and know I want to publish those Content Types in an automated/less work intensive way.

Is there a way to publish multiple Content Types at once from a Content Type Hub?